# Can you use cache in phonegap to save images or access a folder inside android?

Tags: javascript, android, image, caching, phonegap

Can you use cache in phonegap to save images or access a folder inside android?

Comment: yes, images can be saved by the browser it self or by the developer, by saving it to the file system

Comment: the file system and folders can be accessed aswell with plugins like https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/